# Hiding Rows based on other Row Data

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that I am building where I need to Hide specific Rows based on another Row single Column not entire row. Attach is a screenshot of the report showing the Rows highlighted that I want to remove(hide). I cannot seem to find a way to do this without removing other rows I want to keep. Any suggestions would be great. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVHmR.jpg)

I tried to hide the Row based on the `=IIF(Fields!CHARNAME.Value = Previous(Fields!CHARNAME.Value),True,False)` it did not hide the row. I think because the entire row is not the same (but not sure if that is true or I did something wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the expression refers to `CHARNAME` but looking at the example you posted, the 2nd row is not the same as the first, under the CHARNAME column (unless I'm not understanding correctly), the first row is `ADHESION TAPE 2" = RIGHT MIDDLE` and the 2nd row is `ADHESION TAPE 2"`.

Secondly, I think the dataset query must return the data in the same order as your report in order for `PREVIOUS` to work.

Also, it might be easier to omit the rows you want to hide in the dataset query rather than returning all the data and then hiding half of it.

If you wanted to collapse the rows so that they can be expanded and viewed on demand, then you could have two row groups in your report and hide the child group by default.

If this does not help, edit your question to show a sample of data from the dataset query and explain what the report should look like.

Comment: Ok Alan I appreciate the fast response on this one. I was able to correct it via filtering the Dataset. I also did not realize I was using the wrong field in the Expression (tunnel vision from building too many reports lately) .

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working, and tunnel vision writing reports is an occupational hazard!